# CloudQueueClient.ResponseReceived Event broken?

Tags: azure, azure-queues

I'm trying to build an event driven Azure Queue where a event is to fired every time a message is put in the Azure Queue. With AzureXplorer I see that the messages are put in the Azure Queue properly but the CloudQueueClient.ResponseReceived Event never fires. I'm using Azure V1.4. This is the code from my Worker role:

```
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {            
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

        }
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        var queuDataSource = new AzureQueueDataSource();
        queuDataSource.GetCloudQueueClient().ResponseReceived +=new EventHandler<ResponseReceivedEventArgs>(WorkerRole_ResponseReceived);


        // For information on handling configuration changes
        // see the MSDN topic at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=166357.
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    void WorkerRole_ResponseReceived(object sender, ResponseReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var i = 1;  // Breakpoint here never happends
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Azure Queues need to be polled for new messages. See SDK samples or code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff898430.aspx) for examples on how to query queues for new messages.

Quick list of things to take into account:

1. Because polling is counted as a
   transaction in Windows Azure, you
   will be paying for those.
2. It is usually better to implement some kind of retry mechanism if no messages are found (e.g. exponential back-off, etc)
3. It is usually good to retrieve messages in batches (less round trips, less transactions, etc)
4. Remember that messages can be delivered more than once (plan for duplicate messages)
5. Use the "***dequeuecount***" property to deal with "poison messages".

There's plenty of coverage on all these. See the documentation/samples in the link above. This article is pretty good too: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/12/20/best-practices-for-maximizing-scalability-and-cost-effectiveness-of-queue-based-messaging-solutions-on-windows-azure.aspx

Comment: Well, thats just sad. Guess the greedy folk at the marketing department made you do it?! ;) ...

Comment: Well, on the positive side, it's somewhat good to have incentives to build well designed apps, isn't it? And, MS will not make it or break it with queues revenue :-)